# Examples of non-singular hypersurfaces exhibiting Hasse principle failures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Suppose that $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $f$ is a homogenous polynomial of degree $d$. Can we always construct $f$ such that the hypersurface $S_f=\{x \in \mathbb{Z}^n:f(x)=0\}$ exhibits the failure of the Hasse principle? In particular, I am trying to understand why the non-singularity condition in results of Birch (Forms in Many Variables), Browning-Prendiville etc. is vital. I am told that there in case of $d=4$, there is an example of Hasse failure, probably by Swinnerton-Dyer ($S_f$ for $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=7x_1^4+8x_2^4-9x_3^4-14x_4^4$) (not sure how it is a Hasse failure and how easy it is to prove that it is one, but at any rate, it is a non-singular hypersurface that demonstrates that 4 variables are not nearly enough). Can we find more examples of such hypersurfaces which fail to satisfy the hassy principle, for degree $d=4$ or otherwise? I was just hoping to find a large class of examples of such $f$, not just one.

Comment: Can you please clarify the quantifiers in your question? Have you fixed $n$ and $d$ and are looking for a hypersurface of degree $d$ in $n$ variables which fails the Hasse Principle?

Comment: In any case I suspect you will find the following paper of Poonen of Voloch useful: https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/random.pdf

Comment: @DanielLoughran, thanks for the link. Perhaps, I would like to set $d=4$ and $n>48$, since we know that the non-singular quartic hypersurfaces satisfy the Hasse principle for $n>48$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel Loughran's suggestion to study the paper [Random Diophantine Equations by Poonen and Voloch](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/random.pdf) was a good one.

Te conjecture 3.2 of the paper Daniel Loughran linked, together with Appendix A (both due to Colliot-Thélène), implies that the Hasse principle holds for nonsingular hypersurfaces of degree $4$ in $n$ variables as soon as $n>4$.

So, conjecturally, the condition $n>48$ in Browning-Prendiville is not at all necessary, and the $n>48$ condition is "merely" a restriction of the technique.

For $n=4$, there are more counterexamples. The paper [Counterexamples to the Hasse principle in families](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0004972721000885) contains two infinite families along the lines of Swinnerton-Dyer's example.

Comment: thanks! So from the looks of it, there does not seem to be a way to "easily" generate a great many examples of such Hasse failures, right? Also, thanks for interpreting Conjecture 3.2 for me. :)

Comment: @user859588 I think a brute-force computer search using the results of that paper (or maybe another paper) could be viable.